# List and append elements

Tags: python

Something strange - at least to me - is happening in this snippet of code.

I have a function that I recall from a WS method.
My function is something like this:

```
try:       
    tipo = d['id_tipo_offerta']
    params = OFFERTA_MAP_DICT[tipo]
    params.append('days_constraints')
except Exception, s:
    self.log_int_raise("core.struttura._parseDictOfferta(): 1 Error=%s", RED(s))
```

Omitting the content of `OFFERTA_MAP_DICT` (in this specific case is an empty list) I want to know why, if I call this function the first time, value of `params` will be `['days_constraints']` and every other time I recall still this function, value of params will be `['days_constraints','days_constraints',....,'days_constraints']` with *n* elements where *n* is the number of time that I recall this function.

Is my first assignment done by reference?

**Edit**:

Those are my maps

```
OFFERTA_MAP_DICT= {
        ID_OFFERTA_SCONTOCAMERA:    ID_OFFERTA_SCONTOCAMERA_KEYS,
        ID_OFFERTA_BEFOREDATE:      ID_OFFERTA_BEFOREDATE_KEYS,
        ID_OFFERTA_BEFORENDAYS:     ID_OFFERTA_BEFORENDAYS_KEYS,
        ID_OFFERTA_XFORY:           ID_OFFERTA_XFORY_KEYS,
        ID_OFFERTA_SCALARE:         ID_OFFERTA_SCALARE_KEYS,
        ID_OFFERTA_PACCHETTI:       ID_OFFERTA_PACCHETTI_KEYS,
        ID_OFFERTA_LAST_MINUTE:     ID_OFFERTA_LAST_MINUTE_KEYS,
        ID_OFFERTA_ADVANCE:         ID_OFFERTA_ADVANCE_KEYS
        }


OFFERTA_ROOM_MAP_DICT= {
        ID_OFFERTA_SCONTOCAMERA:    ['id_tipo_sconto', 'valore_sconto', 'id_tipo_prezzo'],
        ID_OFFERTA_BEFOREDATE:      ['id_tipo_sconto', 'valore_sconto', 'id_tipo_prezzo'],
        ID_OFFERTA_BEFORENDAYS:     ['id_tipo_sconto', 'valore_sconto', 'id_tipo_prezzo'],
        ID_OFFERTA_XFORY:           [],
        ID_OFFERTA_SCALARE:         [],
        ID_OFFERTA_PACCHETTI:       ['prezzo'],
        ID_OFFERTA_LAST_MINUTE:     ['id_tipo_sconto', 'valore_sconto', 'id_tipo_prezzo']
        }
```

Comment: @delnan -- good point.  Didn't catch that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment is *always* done by reference. If you want to make a (shallow) copy of a list then slice it.

```
lnew = lold[:]
```

Comment: Not strictly true... Python doesn't quite have 'by reference' and 'by value' in the same way that C etc do. But in this case it's a good analogy.

Comment: @StuCox -- If you're going to nitpick, Everything in C is passed by value.  Pass "by reference" is mimicked by passing a pointer by value.  That said, I think that the semantics in this answer are absolutely correct.  Python calls them references,  and assignment is really just the creation of a new reference to the object on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `params = OFFERTA_MAP_DICT[tipo]` assigns `OFFERTA_MAP_DICT[tipo]` to the variable name `params`... it *doesn't* copy it. As `OFFERTA_MAP_DICT[tipo]` is a list, `params` now just points to the same list.

So when you do `params.append('days_constraints')`, you're appending to the list `OFFERTA_MAP_DICT[tipo]`... so when you next come into this block of code, `OFFERTA_MAP_DICT[tipo]` already has 'days_constraints' appended, which you then append again, etc.

You can perform a copy (or deep copy) with the [copy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) module, but depending on how you're using `params` later on, I suspect there may be a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty difficult to really grasp what is happening in your code.  However, when you do:

```
params = OFFERTA_MAP_DICT[tipo]
```

`params` is a reference to *the same list* stored in the `OFFERTA_MAP_DICT`.  When you append to that list, you'll also see that change reflected in `OFFERTA_MAP_DICT` because they share a reference.

Answer (score 0):

`params` is a reference to the same list each time you call the function, and this is the same list as `OFFERTA_MAP_DICT[tipo]`.  So you are repeatedly appending that text to the same list each time.

All assignments in Python assign references. Copying a list can be done in a few ways:

```
params = OFFERTA_MAP_DICT[tipo][:]       # take slice of whole list
params = list(OFFERTA_MAP_DICT[tipo])    # construct new list
params = copy(OFFERTA_MAP_DICT[tipo])    # from copy import copy
```